# Solving ODE numerically with central difference quotient

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods, finite-differences

I try to understand an old Fortran code that is not well documented. In this code the ODE

$$
\frac{dy}{dx} = -\frac{B(x - y)}{y}
$$

is solved numerically as an initial value problem from $x_0=0.99$, $y_0=0.01$ with a step size $h>0$ in negative x-direction. The documentation says that it uses central difference quotient. This would be:

$$
\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{y(x + h) - y(x - h)}{2h}.
$$

The code calculates $y_n=y(x-h)$ iteratively from following equation

$$
y_n = -\left(\frac{B h}{2}\right) +
    \sqrt{\left(\frac{B h}{2}\right)^2 + B h (2x - y) + y^2}
$$

with $y=y(x)$.

I transformed this to:

$$
\begin{split}\Leftrightarrow \left(y_n + \frac{B h}{2}\right)^2 & =
    \left(\frac{B h}{2}\right)^2 + B h (2x - y) + y^2               \\
\Leftrightarrow y_n^2 + B h y_n - y^2 & = B h (2x - y)              \\
\Leftrightarrow y_n^2 + B h y_n - y^2 - B h x & = B h (x - y)       \\
\Leftrightarrow \frac{y^2 - y_n^2 + B h(x - y_n)}{y h} & =
    -\frac{B (x - y)}{y}.\end{split}
$$

I would like to know how the left hand side in the last line of these equations relates to the central difference quotient. Is there some approximation used? I also solved this ODE with a forward difference quotient. The results are similar, so I think the formula in the code is correct, but I would like to understand why.